# Excel find item with Max Average rate within list of items

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I have an "Item Id" and "User Reviews" Columns. There are only 2 columns (A nd B) and there are thousands of rows. All these items have reviews with scoring 1 to 5. I want to find the Item Id which has the highest average score of all items and has more than 100 reviews.

For example "Item Id 1" had 1000 reviews of average score 2.5 , "Item Id 2" had 2000 reviews of average score 3 "Item Id 3" had 50 reviews of average score 4. I want the formula to return "Item Id 2" which has the highest average of 3 because "Item Id 3" had 50 reviews which is less than 100.

| Item Id | User Reviews |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 15 | 3 |

[image]

So far I have this array formula which return the average of the Item with the Maximum review score, i need to add the condition of minimum 100 reviews and return the item Id rather than the Average itself.

```
{=MAX(AVERAGEIF(A:A,A:A,B:B))}
```

Comment: have you tried looking into `Power Query` if none of the solutions has worked as per your conditions. I think it would be easy with few steps. Group By `Item ID` click on `Advanced` in `Group By` window . New Column Name `All` --> `Operation` --> `Count Rows` add a aggregation as `Average` --> Operation as --> `Average` --> `User Reviews` --> Press Ok --> Now add this in formula bar `Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"All", Order.Descending},{"Average", Order.Descending}})` and lastly `= Table.FirstN(#"Sorted Rows",1)` which gives you the `Item Id` with max of reviews along continue

Comment: With the highest average. Also Note `Power Query` is applicable from 2016+ onwards, for excel 2010 & 2013 Microsoft has ended their support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you don't have O365 as per your comment and adding the additional condition of a minimum of `x`-reviews, you can try the following formula (to illustrate the point I am using a minimum of `2`-reviews)

```
=LET(A,A2:A8, B,B2:B8, ux,UNIQUE(A), avg,AVERAGEIFS(B,A,ux),
 cnts, COUNTIFS(A, ux), f,IF(cnts>=2,avg,-1),INDEX(ux, MATCH(MAX(f),f,0)))
```

or using `FILTER` function:

```
=LET(A,A2:A8, B,B2:B8, ux,UNIQUE(A), avg,AVERAGEIFS(B,A,ux),
 cnts, COUNTIFS(A, ux), FILTER(ux,avg=MAX((cnts>=2)* avg)))
```

I am assuming the review are all positive, so I use the IF condition to exclude the review with a minimum number of reviews, considering a negative average.
output:
[image: output]

As you can see item `4` has the maximum average review, but this item is excluded, because it has only one review.

Since we don't know your excel version, I am assuming we can use `LET`, `UNIQUE`, or `FILTER` functions available for Excel 2021.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't have Office365, it is Excel standard and don't have XLOOKUP formula, also there is a condition that minimum user review count must be 100

Comment: @st_user_321122 without knowing your Excel version, it is difficult to provide a solution. Please next time in the tag list your Excel version, so we can provide a solution that works for that version.

Comment: @st_user_321122 I updated my answer to consider the minimum condition, assuming some of the functions I use you have them, since we don't know your excel version

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
=LET(α, A2:A7, 
     β, B2:B7, 
     @SORTBY(α, AVERAGEIFS(β, α, α), -1)
)
```

***Edit**: for older versions of Excel, assuming the entries in `B2:B7` are non-negative*:

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/AVERAGEIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,A2:A7)),A2:A7)
```

Comment: @st_user_321122 Added an alternative, with a condition on the values in `B2:B7`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't have Office365, it is Excel standard and don't have @SORTBYformula, also there is a condition that the minimum user review count must be 100

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jos, is it also possible to add this condition "user review count must be mimum 100" ?

Comment: I think you need to add a more realistic dataset to your post, together with new expected results.

Comment: Ok I have added a screenshot and a minimum of 100 reviews condition was in the question

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, i think Power query is more suited here. I tried the formula with the older version, but it is not matching with the required criteria. Because if you see per OP's new screenshot data, your formula output gives 10 and with PQ i am getting as 24 as 10 has 7 counts while 24 has 8 counts which is max. I am assuming the max count is 8, if the max count of review is 7 then 10 works but otherwise it should be 24. Correct me If i am wrong here.